# cython error Cannot assign to private of outer parallel block

Tags: python, parallel-processing, openmp, cython, python-multithreading

I tried to find a solution to this error both here at SO and at the Cython user's forum but could not find it answered. When I tested the very same parallelism example as provided in the documentation [Cython 0.23.1 documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/parallelism.html), then I get the error attached below. What am I missing ? How should it be implemented ? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

### Here is the code from cython documentation

```
from cython.parallel import parallel, prange
from libc.stdlib cimport abort, malloc, free

cdef Py_ssize_t idx, i, n = 100
cdef int * local_buf
cdef size_t size = 10
with nogil, parallel():
    local_buf = <int *> malloc(sizeof(int) * size)
if local_buf == NULL:
    abort()

# populate our local buffer in a sequential loop
for i in xrange(size):
    local_buf[i] = i * 2

# share the work using the thread-local buffer(s)
for i in prange(n, schedule='guided'):
    func(local_buf)

free(local_buf)

# I just simply added this to test it
cdef void func(int* local_buf) nogil:
cdef int i=0
return
```

### And here is the error

```
'''
Compiling thread_local.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing thread_local.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
# populate our local buffer in a sequential loop
for i in xrange(size):
    local_buf[i] = i * 2

# share the work using the thread-local buffer(s)
for i in prange(n, schedule='guided'):
     ^
------------------------------------------------------------

thread_local.pyx:19:10: Cannot assign to private of outer parallel block
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "setup.py", line 28, in <module>
 ext_modules = cythonize(extensions),)
 File "/apps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-  packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 877, in cythonize
cythonize_one(*args)
File "/apps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-     packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 997, in cythonize_one
raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: thread_local.pyx
```

Comment: (Untested but) I think it's just getting confused at you reusing variables. Try using a different name for the second loop.

Comment: Thanks David. Working just fine now.

Comment: Wait, are the indentations here correct?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to DavidW, his educated guess was right. I am not quite sure why but it seems that you cannot reuse the same variable (in this case `i` ) for both for loops inside a `with nogil, parallel():` block. I guess the intention of the authors was to use separate variables for both of the `for` loops, since I see that another variable is defined, `idx`, but was left unused.  I hope they correct this misleading example.

```
from cython.parallel import parallel, prange
from libc.stdlib cimport abort, malloc, free

cdef Py_ssize_t idx, i, n = 100
cdef int * local_buf
cdef size_t size = 10

with nogil, parallel():
    local_buf = <int *> malloc(sizeof(int) * size)
    if local_buf == NULL:
        abort()

# populate our local buffer in a sequential loop
    for i in xrange(size):
        local_buf[i] = i * 2

# share the work using the thread-local buffer(s)
    for idx in prange(n, schedule='guided'):
        func(local_buf)

    free(local_buf)
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much for the tip. What an unclear error message :(